# Stripe Payment Gateway MVC C3

Tags: model-view-controller, stripe-payments

Can Anyone Please Help me to how to implement Stripe Payment Gateway In MVC C# I tried Lot of examples but they didnt work please help me with scratch and simplified examples.
Any Solution Will Be Appreciated .
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use third party library for C# as there is no official library for C# by Stripe.

You look this [library](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net) or you can see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#c-sharp) for others